# Client component communication with Relay?

Tags: reactjs, redux, relayjs

Inside react-relay app I need to change my sidenav component based on  state of main content component.

Is it any simple global store for client component communication? Would it be ok to use dummy mutation and bounce back or should I keep my state in least common parent?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Redux you can connect your App with the global state. Then both your components can be set-up by passing the same prop to them.

Let say you define your App. In render you should have something like:

```
 render() {
        const {myValue} = this.props;
        return (<div>
                <MyFirstComponent propValue={myValue}/>
                <MySecondComponent propValue={myValue}/>
                </div>
        );
 }
```

Then at the end of the App

```
App.propTypes = {
    myValue: PropTypes.object
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            myValue: state.myReducer.myValue   
        }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

Everytime you dispatch an action which will return an updated value of myValue both the components will be sharing it.

Comment: Thank you, Theo. I am familiar with Redux and I asked how to do the same with relay.js. I heard many times that FB itself uses flux and relay, so probably I should do the same. Thx

Comment: What is the relation of the redux tag then?

Comment: Originally, question ending with GetMeTheHellBackToRedux?, but it got removed by editors :-)

Comment: Why would you have to use a technology just because some other people are using it? I guess FB uses flux and relay for their good reasons. As you know Redux why don't you just use it?